# IE 7 adding underline to icon font elements

Tags: internet-explorer-7, underline, icon-fonts

Hi I have built a site using a font-icon from icomoon as image alternatives. Everything is fine however in ie7 they display with a text-decoration underline.

I have used a class to stop this when used in links which works in all browsers except ie7.
I put the icon in as a data icon in the 'a' and the text for links in a span. And class like so..

```
a.{
text-decoration:none;
}

span{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

This is fine in every browser except ie7???

Even in `<i>` elements it adds a random underline, so again I added a style

```
i{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Still no joy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a dot next to the `a` in your CSS code? `a.{` That doesn't look right. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you think the `a.` selector would do.

I suggest you use a descendant selector:

```
a i {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```